# android - prebuild project apk size increased in target folder

Tags: android

I try to run below prebuild project in aosp code. I found the apk size increased about 18MB after copied to target folder:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE        := com.sample.test
LOCAL_MODULE_OWNER  := personal
LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS   := optional
LOCAL_MODULE_CLASS  := APPS
LOCAL_CERTIFICATE   := platform
LOCAL_MODULE_SUFFIX := .apk
LOCAL_PRIVATE_PLATFORM_APIS := true
LOCAL_SRC_FILES     := ./test.apk
LOCAL_PRODUCT_MODULE := true
LOCAL_PRIVILEGED_MODULE := true

include $(BUILD_PREBUILT)
```

Original test.apk and output apk size (14M to 32M):

```
-rwxrwxr-x 1 me 14M Feb 23 10:42 mytest/test.apk
-rw-rw-r-- 1 me 32M Feb 23 10:43 com.sample.test/com.sample.test.apk
```

What's the reason the prebuilt apk size increased so much?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also found this problem. And I check my apks, the class.dex file gets bigger.

When compiling, if app is priv app and it needs signed, the building system will uncompress class.dex. Check below .mk files:

```
dexpreopt_odex_install.mk
# We explicitly uncompress APKs of privileged apps, and used by
# privileged apps
ifneq (true,$(DONT_UNCOMPRESS_PRIV_APPS_DEXS))
  ifeq (true,$(LOCAL_PRIVILEGED_MODULE))
    LOCAL_UNCOMPRESS_DEX := true
  endif

  ifneq (,$(filter $(PRODUCT_LOADED_BY_PRIVILEGED_MODULES), $(LOCAL_MODULE)))
    LOCAL_UNCOMPRESS_DEX := true
  endif
endif  # DONT_UNCOMPRESS_PRIV_APPS_DEXS

ifeq (,$(filter PRESIGNED,$(LOCAL_CERTIFICATE)))
    # Store uncompressed dex files preopted in /system
    ifeq ($(BOARD_USES_SYSTEM_OTHER_ODEX),true)
      ifeq ($(call install-on-system-other, $(my_module_path)),)
        LOCAL_UNCOMPRESS_DEX := true
      endif  # install-on-system-other
    else  # BOARD_USES_SYSTEM_OTHER_ODEX
      LOCAL_UNCOMPRESS_DEX := true
    endif
endif

app_prebuilt_internal.mk
...
ifeq (true, $(LOCAL_UNCOMPRESS_DEX))
$(uncompress-dexs)
...

definitions.mk
# Uncompress dex files embedded in an apk.
#
define uncompress-dexs
  if (zipinfo $@ '*.dex' 2>/dev/null | grep -v ' stor ' >/dev/null) ; then \
    $(ZIP2ZIP) -i $@ -o $@.tmp -0 "classes*.dex" && \
    mv -f $@.tmp $@ ; \
  fi
endef
```

There are two steps to let apk size do not increase:

1. Set this in BoardConfig.mk

   DONT_UNCOMPRESS_PRIV_APPS_DEXS := true.
2. change value from platform to PRESIGNED in your app's mk.(And you need sign your apk by yourself)

   LOCAL_CERTIFICATE   := PRESIGNED

Comment: Thanks, good findings! Do you think use compressed dex will impact on performance? it need runtime decompress, which will cost some CPU cycles!

Comment: Yes, I commented the implementation of uncompress-dexs, so that the dex of all priv apps is not decompressed, and found that the system startup time is slowed down